# C# WPF ribbon:RibbonTextBox vs. TextBox

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

After installing Microsoft Ribbon for WPF, I create a WPF Ribbon Application. For textbox, I have choices of "ribbon:RibbonTextBox" or "TextBox" - they seems to work the same to me. Anyone know of the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RibbonTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbontextbox.aspx) class implements [ICommandSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.aspx), which allows it to integrate with the WPF command framework.

For instance, a command can be invoked when the text box has the input focus and the `RETURN` key is pressed, or the text box can disable itself when its associated command cannot be executed.